# Spark - Random Number Generation

Tags: scala, random, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have written a method that must consider a random number to simulate a Bernoulli distribution. I am using `random.nextDouble` to generate a number between 0 and 1 then making my decision based on that value given my probability parameter.

My problem is that Spark is generating the same random numbers within each iteration of my for loop mapping function. I am using the `DataFrame` API. My code follows this format:

```
val myClass = new MyClass()
val M = 3
val myAppSeed = 91234
val rand = new scala.util.Random(myAppSeed)

for (m <- 1 to M) {
  val newDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(myDF
    .map{row => RowFactory
      .create(row.getString(0),
        myClass.myMethod(row.getString(2), rand.nextDouble())
    }, myDF.schema)
}
```

Here is the class:

```
class myClass extends Serializable {
  val q = qProb

  def myMethod(s: String, rand: Double) = {
    if (rand <= q) // do something
    else // do something else
  }
}
```

I need a new random number every time `myMethod` is called. I also tried generating the number inside my method with `java.util.Random` (`scala.util.Random` v10 does not extend `Serializable`) like below, but I'm still getting the same numbers within each for loop

```
val r = new java.util.Random(s.hashCode.toLong)
val rand = r.nextDouble()
```

I've done some research, and it seems this has do to with Sparks deterministic nature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why the same sequence is repeated is that the random generator is created and initialized with a seed before the data is partitioned. Each partition then starts from the same random seed. Maybe not the most efficient way to do it, but the following should work:

```
val myClass = new MyClass()
val M = 3

for (m <- 1 to M) {
  val newDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(myDF
    .map{ 
       val rand = scala.util.Random
       row => RowFactory
      .create(row.getString(0),
        myClass.myMethod(row.getString(2), rand.nextDouble())
    }, myDF.schema)
}
```

Comment: I modified this slightly to solve my problem. I passed the Random val into my method and generated random numbers from within there. This solved my problem, but I had to use `java.util.Random` for serializeability reasons.

Answer (score 18):

Just use the SQL function `rand`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

//df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [key: int]

df.select($"key", rand() as "rand").show
+---+-------------------+
|key|               rand|
+---+-------------------+
|  1| 0.8635073400704648|
|  2| 0.6870153659986652|
|  3|0.18998048357873532|
+---+-------------------+


df.select($"key", rand() as "rand").show
+---+------------------+
|key|              rand|
+---+------------------+
|  1|0.3422484248879837|
|  2|0.2301384925817671|
|  3|0.6959421970071372|
+---+------------------+
```

Comment: This didn't quite solve my problem, but its an elegant solution that I will likely be using in the future, so +1

Answer (score 6):

According to [this post](https://wegetsignal.wordpress.com/2015/05/08/generating-random-numbers-for-rdd-in-spark/), the best solution is not to put the `new scala.util.Random` inside the map, nor completely outside (ie. in the driver code), but in an intermediate `mapPartitionsWithIndex`:

```
import scala.util.Random
val myAppSeed = 91234
val newRDD = myRDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex { (indx, iter) =>
   val rand = new scala.util.Random(indx+myAppSeed)
   iter.map(x => (x, Array.fill(10)(rand.nextDouble)))
}
```

Comment: Had to maintain a code that used this solution and want to share with the community that this solution has its downsides and probably will badly influence your statistical analysis, please be aware of. When you have an rdd that has partition>1, your rdd sequence of random numbers will start over again for each partition with new seed and different numbers, but it may change the 'characteristics' of the whole sequence. My advice: don't use this approach.

Comment: @d-xa thanks for you comment. Could you recommend an alternative approach?

Comment: if one uses this approach I would suggest to fix the partition for myRDD to 1

Answer (score 1):

Using Spark Dataset API, perhaps for use in an accumulator:

```
df.withColumn("_n", substring(rand(),3,4).cast("bigint"))
```